# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context + Visual Studio 2019 + Windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Newbie here struggling the way into the Matrix. I'am coding my first program ( VS 2019), and using a `WinForms` Application I get the following error

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltkc7.png)

Since this code is autogenerated I have no clue of what can be wrong

Comment: There is a Form1.Designer.cs in your solution window. Check that the InitializeComponent will be there (as its the other part of Partial Class). If its still problematic. Delete the Form1 and add a new Windows Form. That should fix the issue (unless something wrong with your project templates).

Comment: Perhaps you changed the namespace in your Form1.cs file but this file contains a partial class. The remainder of your class is in a file named Form1.designer.cs. You will find the InitializeComponent there, but the namespace now is different and the compiler cannot find it. Fix the namespace also in the designer.cs file. If you copied this form from an example, either add an empty method called "InitializeComponent" to this class or remove this method call from your constructor. Or maybe start it from scratch in VS.

Comment: Look into `From1.Designer.cs` and check that the namespaces match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr;** Update the files (Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs) as needed to ensure that they define the relevant parts of the the *same* partial class - namespace and class name.

The InitializeComponent method (and components) should be defined in a *partial code-behind* for the design surface. In this case that is `Form1.Designer.cs` - inspect *that file* to resolve the error.

The compilation error sounds like the classes are in *different namespaces* or *different type names* (and thus are *not* `partial` to eachother), possibly from invalid generation or an unsynchronized change.

- Form1.cs's Form1 class cannot find the InitializeComponent method which should be defined via the partial in Form1.Designer.cs; and
- Form1.Design.cs cannot override Dispose which comes from the Form base-type inherited from Form1 in Form1.cs.

From the shown code, both files should have a `Form1` class defined namespace `strnull`.

Note: the `strnull` namespace seems odd, perhaps an invalid template / generator. Update both files as needed to ensure that they define the relevant parts of the the *same* partial class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time for the full explanation, cheers!